# Accessing event.data from handler of input on textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been looking arround for a couple of days on this matter.

For some background I will explain the objective:
  I have a textarea and I want that when I type some special character defined by me (like @) it detects it as a part of a dictionary and show an autocomplete floating dive to choose from and if it's not in the dictionary it adds it.

The current status / problem is that I'm trying to capture the changes in the textarea with the input event and it works, it runs the handler code exactly when I want but I'm not able to access the data.

I guess I could capture the paste event and the key up events and take the clipboard from one and the key code from the other but I wonder if there is a way I can do it with the input event.

Here the relevant code:

```js
function checkLastCharacter(event){
  console.log(event);
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    //$( "#update" ).click(updateClick);
    var text=document.getElementById("text");
    text.addEventListener("input", checkLastCharacter);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="text" rows="4" cols="50">Sample text</textarea>
```

**Result of execution:** No mater what key I press or if I paste or not anything it shows:

> "event: undefined"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the "input" event does not have the property "data". You have to read the text manually from the target property: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Events/input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

EDIT:

This will handle the paste event from the clipboard. You will need to parse char by char to handle your specific token to show whatever you need to show.

```
$('target').on('paste', function () {
  var element = this;
  setTimeout(function () {
    var text = $(element).val();
    // do something with text
  }, 100);
});
```

---

---

---

You will be much better of using jquerys [`.keypress()`](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/) There's even an example on that page of capturing every keystroke (and a bunch of other information as well):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>keypress demo</title>
  <style>
  fieldset {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
  }
  input {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .25em;
  }
  #print-output {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .print-output-line {
    white-space: pre;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: monaco, monospace;
    font-size: .7em;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="target">Type Something:</label>
    <input id="target" type="text">
  </fieldset>
</form>
<button id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</button>
<script src="/resources/events.js"></script>

<script>
var xTriggered = 0;
$( "#target" ).keypress(function( event ) {
  if ( event.which == 13 ) {
     event.preventDefault();
  }
  xTriggered++;
  var msg = "Handler for .keypress() called " + xTriggered + " time(s).";
  $.print( msg, "html" );
  $.print( event );
});

$( "#other" ).click(function() {
  $( "#target" ).keypress();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The output of this script is:

```
Handler for .keypress() called 21 time(s).
{
originalEvent: [object KeyboardEvent],
type: keypress,
isDefaultPrevented: function returnFalse() {
    return false;
},
timeStamp: 41095.395000000004,
jQuery1102038791229348009115: true,
keyCode: 114,
key: r,
charCode: 114,
char: undefined,
which: 114,
view: [object Window],
target: <input id="target">,
shiftKey: false,
relatedTarget: undefined,
metaKey: false,
eventPhase: 2,
currentTarget: <input id="target">,
ctrlKey: false,
cancelable: true,
bubbles: true,
altKey: false,
delegateTarget: <input id="target">,
handleObj: [object Object],
data: null,
isPropagationStopped: function returnFalse() {
    return false;
},
isImmediatePropagationStopped: function returnFalse() {
    return false;
},
preventDefault: function () {
        var e = this.originalEvent;

        this.isDefaultPrevented = returnTrue;
        if ( !e ) {
            return;
        }

        // If preventDefault exists, run it on the original event
        if ( e.preventDefault ) {
            e.preventDefault();

        // Support: IE
        // Otherwise set the returnValue property of the original event to false
        } else {
            e.returnValue = false;
        }
    },
stopPropagation: function () {
        var e = this.originalEvent;

        this.isPropagationStopped = returnTrue;
        if ( !e ) {
            return;
        }
        // If stopPropagation exists, run it on the original event
        if ( e.stopPropagation ) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        }

        // Support: IE
        // Set the cancelBubble property of the original event to true
        e.cancelBubble = true;
    },
stopImmediatePropagation: function () {
        this.isImmediatePropagationStopped = returnTrue;
        this.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for your answer. This doesnt work for clipboard paste

Comment: Hey! Take a look at the event paste for jquery. At that time you will have the entire text at hand, it won't be a specific character so you will have to go char by char and then do your special handling. Edited response to add the paste event.

Answer (score 0):

`event.data` its wrong syntax .if you need a value of the `textarea` use

```
 console.log(event.target.value);
```

**or**

```
 function checkLastCharacter(event,this){
  console.log(this.value);
}
```

```js
function checkLastCharacter(event){
  console.log(event.target.value);
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    //$( "#update" ).click(updateClick);
    var text=document.getElementById("text");
    text.addEventListener("input", checkLastCharacter);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="text" rows="4" cols="50">
     ASfadfasbncaksjb 
 </textarea>
```

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for your answer. The problem is I don't want the full textarea content. I just want the "new characters".